# GAE User authentication on website

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am currently hosting a website on Google App Engine with the domain appspot.com

One feature I would like to implement into my website with the help of Google App Engine is 'user authentication', I would like to be able to create the function using the Jinja2 templating language.

I have resources explaining the process on how to do this for a GAE app, however, I was wondering if there were any way I could complete this functionality using a language such as Jinja2 for a website?

And then creating a html template using Jinja2 and then linking the template page which would work with the main.py and app.yaml file, with a page from my website.

An example of what I would like to create is below

I have a 'Contact' page on my website from this page I would like there to be a link from a button on the contact page to a 'user login' page. I would like this login page to be created using Python, webapp2, Jinja2 etc.and then the user to login with their Google Account.

My app.yaml currently

```
application: wrestlingsite
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: wfiles/homepage.html
  upload: wfiles/homepage.html

- url: /
  static_dir: wfiles

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

Is this possible? As from looking over some GAE documentation it only mentions using this feature with a GAE app.

Comment: Jinja2 is not in any way a framework, it is simply a template language.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a walk thru of the python tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

This tutorial touches on user authentication as well as what do to with jinja.